# Trying to build an array of nested arrays to map N associations deep in a Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a `Skill` model, which has many prerequisites (or `prereqs` in my model), and I need to create a map N-levels deep of the prerequisites for a skill, because I need to pass this information to Javascript (with the gon gem in my controller) for some crazy, HTML5/KineticJS action that shows the birds eye view of the relationship between this skill and others.

Right now, the code below is working great to consistently map 5 levels deep.

```
delegate :url_helpers, to: 'Rails.application.routes'

def prereqs_map
  prereqs_array = [ self.title.to_s, url_helpers.skill_path(self), Array.new(prereqs) ]
  prereqs_array[2] = prereqs_array[2].map do |prereq1|
    prereq1 = [ prereq1.title.to_s, url_helpers.skill_path(prereq1), Array.new(prereq1.prereqs).map do |prereq2|
      prereq2 = [ prereq2.title.to_s, url_helpers.skill_path(prereq2), Array.new(prereq2.prereqs).map do |prereq3|
        prereq3 = [ prereq3.title.to_s, url_helpers.skill_path(prereq3), Array.new(prereq3.prereqs).map do |prereq4|
          prereq4 = [ prereq4.title.to_s, url_helpers.skill_path(prereq4), Array.new(prereq4.prereqs).map do |prereq5|
            prereq5 = [ prereq5.title.to_s, url_helpers.skill_path(prereq5), [] ]
          end ] # prereq depth 5
        end ] # prereq depth 4
      end ] # prereq depth 3
    end ] # prereq depth 2
  end   # prereq depth 1

  return prereqs_array
end
```

The problem, as you can see, is it's super messy with nested maps and there's no way that I can figure out to pass a `depth` parameter and have the method map out to whatever depth I pass it.

I figure there has to be a better way of doing this. Any thoughts?

Comment: seems like a perfect candidate for recursion but it's really hard to understand how it works

Comment: do you confirm `prereq1.prereqs` is an Integer?

Comment: @apneadiving It does seem a perfect candidate for recursion, but I couldn't figure out how to use recursion for this. prereq1.prereqs is not an integer. It's an array of other skills that have been added to this skill as prereqs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Skill
  # has many prereqs?

  def prereqs_map(depth = 5)
    mapping = Proc.new do |node, depth, current_level|
      [node.title.to_s, url_helpers.skill_path(node), node.prereqs.map {|prereq| mapping.call(prereq, depth, current_level+1)}] if current_level <= depth
    end
    mapping.call(self, depth, 0)
  end

end

>> skill.prereqs_map(5)
```

Comment: sorry, updating now with depth

Comment: Elegant and it works perfectly. Thanks for teaching me something new!

Answer (score 1):

By adding an instance method "to_tree" to your model, you can recurse over it. The following randomly sets up a tree of dependencies, and then gives you an array of arrays in your required format.

```
class Skill

  attr_accessor :prereqs
  attr_accessor :title

  def randomly_create_tree depth=0
    self.title = ["Coding", "Winning", "Smiling", "Eating"][rand(4)]
    if depth < 3
      self.prereqs = []
      (0..rand(3)).each do
        skill = Skill.new
        skill.randomly_create_tree(depth + 1)
        self.prereqs << skill
      end
    else
      self.prereqs = []
    end
    self
  end

  def to_tree
    prereqs.collect do |prereq|
      [self.title, prereq.to_tree]
    end
  end
```

And then:

```
s = Skill.new
s.randomly_create_tree
s.to_tree
```

Results in:

```
[["Coding", [["Winning", [["Winning", []], ["Winning", []]]]]]]
```

Where each of the strings is a randomly generated title. You'll probably want to add in your  url_helpers.skill_path too but I'm not sure what that does.

Comment: Something like this may have worked, but I found the example with creating a random tree a little confusing, since most of what's there is not what I want to do; prerequisite relationships already exist in associations and I just want to map those into an array. Valery's answer below is exactly what I was looking for though.